# Wait for an NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I have code that sends away a `HTTP POST` connection. I want the method to wait until I get a response from the server for it to continue. The reason I am doing it this way is because I am integrating new code (asynchronous post vs the old synchronous post) into our application and I am looking for minimal change throughout the application.

The old method was as follows:

```
-(NSData*) postData: (NSString*) strData;
```

The application would call it and send it a `strData` object and it would lock the main thread until it got something back. This was inefficient but it worked well, but due to timeout constraints I have to change it.

So my new method (posting the complete method here) is as follows:

```
-(NSData*) postData: (NSString*) strData
{
    //start http request code
    //postString is the STRING TO BE POSTED
    NSString *postString;
    //this is the string to send
    postString = @"data=";
    postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:strData]; 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MYSERVERURL"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];
    //setting prarameters of the POST connection
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"en-US" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Language"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:20]; //one second for testing purposes
    NSLog(@"%@",postString);    
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
    //end http request code
    return receivedData; //this is set by a delegate somewhere else in the code
}
```

It sends the code fine, but of course (and as expected), it does not receive it fast enough to be returned correctly.

What do you recommend I can do to "stop" that method to wait to return anything until something is received? I've tried setting a while loop that waited on a `BOOL` that would be set to `YES` when all data was received, but that loop prevented the code from sending at all. I also tried throwing the contents of this method into another method and calling it to `performSelectorInBackground`, but of course, that didn't work either. I'm running out of ideas and I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing any sort of synchronous comms on the main thread is a bad idea, but if you can't re-architect at this point then take a look at:

> +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]

The documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). From the discussion:

> A synchronous load is built on top of the asynchronous loading code
>   made available by the class. The calling thread is blocked while the
>   asynchronous loading system performs the URL load on a thread spawned
>   specifically for this load request. No special threading or run loop
>   configuration is necessary in the calling thread in order to perform a
>   synchronous load.

But seriously, take a look and how much work would be involved in performing the request asynchronously and receiving a notification when the request is complete. The whole experience for the user is going to be much better.

Comment: Well I'm trying to keep the current code (above) as it is because I need to implement a timeout of less than 240 seconds, which can only happen with an asynchronous connection and not a synchronous connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually performing an asynchronous request there.

In order to do a synchronous request, you should use `+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error` in the `NSURLConnection` Class.

It is indeed a bad idea though to block the app while you are doing this and therefore it is usually discouraged.

Cheers