# Method Sleep Until Notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, delay

Is there any way that I can have a method sleep until a notification is posted? This is for an asynchronous `NSURLConnection`. I cannot move to a synchronous connection for multiple reasons.

Comment: This seems an awful lot like a double-post of the problem in [Wait for an NSURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572713/wait-for-an-nsurlconnection)? Please don't do that.

Comment: If a method sleeps, it sleeps with the fishes.  It locks up the UI and iOS will kill the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods cannot "sleep"; that only applies to threads. Just split the code that needs to wait out into another method and have that method called when the notification arrives.

```
- (void) doStuffBeforeConnection {

    [self doPreConnectionStuff];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/U/R/L"];

    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                         timeoutInterval:0];
    NSURLConnection * conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
                                                         delegate:self];

    return;
    // We are now "waiting"...
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    [self nowDoStuffThatNeededToWait:response];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use addobserver and set a target class with selector to be fired on notification.
when you need to trigger, use postNotification with notificatonName.
there you go..!!

Comment: observer can be added and Notification can be posted by using [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]

Comment: Is there any way to do it without adding a different method selector?

Comment: as you mentioned "until a notification is posted" so it need a selector to respond to the Notification. if there is no selector attached with a notification then there is no purpose to Post a notification.

Comment: How about any alternate ways? I just need the method to halt and wait until the delegate says it has a response.

Comment: well I know pretty much verity of programming languages but in all, you can pause the execution of a method at a statement with pause calls such as - sleep(milliseconds) by one syntax or the other depending on language but you cannot set a conditional pause in the middle of a method. You somehow have to find a way to make your code compliant to use delegates by use of custom/existing protocols. that's the best which could be done..